# Setting independent colorbar scale to y-values of plot using matplotlib and proplot

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I have a series of histograms that I plot over the top of each other using a for loop:

```
import matplotlib as plt
import proplot as pplt
cmap = colormap
fig = pplt.figure(figsize=(12, 10), dpi=300)
jj = [ 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

for j in jj:
    
     plt.fill_between(p[:,j], s[:, j], y2=0, alpha = 0.6, color = colormap[:,4-j], edgecolor=[0,0,0], linewidth=1.5)
```

The colormap in question is a manually specified list of RGB triplets (from Fabio Crameri's 'lajolla' map):

`0.64566    0.823453    0.895061    0.924676    0.957142`

`0.277907   0.386042    0.526882    0.657688    0.803006`

`0.259453   0.301045    0.317257    0.331596    0.408285`

Each color corresponds to data recorded  under different conditions. I want the colorbar to have manually specified ticks corresponding to this variable (e.g. c = 30, 35, 40, 45, 50), but I can't seem to configure the colormap to not just pull the indices of the cmap matrix (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) as the values of the mapped variable. Trying to set the ticks outside of this range just result in them not being shown.

`cbar = fig.colorbar(np.transpose(cmap))`

`cbar.set_ticks([30, 35, 40, 45, 50])`

`cbar.set_ticklabels([30, 35, 40, 45, 50])`

Any idea how I can resolve this?

[image]

Tried shifting indices of colormap but this doesn't seem to work.

Trying to get the colorbar with ticks corresponding to the '30, 35, 40, 45, 50' values quoted above.